# Blazor server app memory usage success story

Tags: memory-leaks, blazor, blazor-server-side

We have an enterprise application built using server side Blazor and hosted in Azure.  With increased app usage, the memory allocation to the app service would just keep climbing until we would get to 90-100% of our allocated memory.  Everything we read seemed to indicate we didn't really need to do anything and the normal garbage collection processes would keep things running smoothly.

We started reading things online about folks implementing IDisposable on their pages to try and clean things up.  We tried a few things and nothing really seemed to help until we did a memory analysis using Visual Studio's analytics.  We noticed that large lists of data were not released from the heap and the data grids that used this data were also not being released.

So, we went through the whole app and implemented IDisposable on all pages and any components that used data grids and contained large lists of data.  In the Dispose methods be cleared all data and nulled out any data grids that used the data.  Also as a bit of over kill we requested a garbage collection as well.

Results:

Prior to this change, normal resting state of the app was around 40-50% memory used and would jump to 90-100% used when the app was active.

After the IDisposable implementation, resting state of the app sat around 20-25%, and maxed out at just less than 35%.

This was a truly remarkable outcome.  Please tell me this is all wrong or tell me about your successes as well so we can help others with this issue.

We implemented IDisposable and it worked.

Comment: Can you share your implementation of IDisposable?

Comment: "until we would get to 90-100%" - but did you have any problems?  This sounds like the GC just doesn't kick until it's needed.

Comment: We don't have any special implementation.  The component implements IDisposable and we clean up large collections of data and de-reference any grids that used those collections.  Also, unreference any event handlers created.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly treating the symptoms, not the root cause.

When the Renderer removes a component from the render tree, it checks if the component implements `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable`.  If it does, it calls the correct dispose method before it drops it's reference to the component.  Once complete, there should be no references to the component and the next GC run will release the memory space it occupied.

If however, you hold a reference to that component elsewhere, the Renderer will still dispose the component, but the the GC won't clear it.

What you are desribing is exactly that.  You must be holding a reference to a parent/grandparent component in a long lived object such as a service or in the layout.

Once you figure that out and fix it, all your disposal implementation stuff will almost certainly be irrelevant.

Comment: We are also un-referencing event handlers created in the component as well.  For better or worse we do create large collections of data on the server and if these are not cleared out in the dispose method they just seem to hang out which causes the memory to balloon quickly.

What harm are we causing by cleaning up after ourselves right away when a component is disposed.

Comment: You aren't.  But I guarantee you have a fundamental design flaw that is causing the problem in the first place.  You need to solve it or it will come back to bite you.  Which grid control are you using?  How are you creating and using `DbContext`s?  A common problem is using Transient Services that require disposing.  But your issue seems to be with components not being cleared.

Comment: OK, now you have me thinking.  This app is somewhat inherited and have been refactoring over the last year.  Our IDbConnection is Transient, so we create a new instance for every query.  Should the DbContext be scoped or should we try to dispose the IDbConnection after each query is run.

Also, Telerik Blazor Grid.

Comment: You should be using an `IDbContextFactory` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor  This answer explains why you shouldn't use Transient - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146131/c-sharp-blazor-server-transient-services-dispose

Comment: We are not using EntityFramework, so that will probably not work.  We were using transient because our code uses two separate databases and the connection string is updated on the fly depending on the db needed.  (Petty goofy)  I created  IDbConnection for each database and created a scoped service for each connection.  Seems to work fine.