# c# Blazor server transient services dispose

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on Blazor server application and I am blocked / confused about using transient type services inside Blazor server.

I have readed [this topic](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26676) on why I should not implement IDisposable inside transient service.

> **Transient services which implement IDisposable** :
> A reference to the service is maintained by the DI container so it can handle service disposal. This prevents garbage collection of the service upon component disposal. The service is kept in memory till the DI container itself can be garbage collected.

**My question is**:
Is it okey if I implement IDisposable inside my transient service, and call `.Dispose()` inside my `.razor` when I dont need it anymore?

**Lets create example**:

Example service registed as transient inside DI:

```
namespace testExample
{
    public class MyService : IDisposable
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            

        }
    }
}
```

Example component:

```
@inject MyService _service

@implements IDisposable

<h3>MyComponent</h3>


@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _service.DoSomething();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _service.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I tried this example up and by looking at memory and tracking how many instances are created, it seems that example is valid and can be used, but lack of my knowledge is still making me unsecured about this approach.

Comment: First of all `IDisposable` is used to clean up unmanaged resources. You can check this detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface.

Second, if you don't implement the methods of an interface, then why do you use that interface after all? In your example, `public void Dispose() {}` does nothing.

Comment: @TeodorVladutu thank you for reply.
I readed question you send, some things are little bit more clean now.
Also I'm implementing interface for several reasons. 
First: To be able to use 'using' word before declaring my service.
Second: For some debug logging after dispose...
But my question is more related to problem of transient services inside blazor server, because I found several solutions.

Comment: @TeodorVladutu IDisposable is *not* used just to clean up resources, it's used to control lifetime as well. A DbContext has no managed resources and yet is an `IDisposable` as part of its Unit-of-Work implementation. It's *very* common to use `IDisposable` to control the lifetime of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request a Transient service it's provided by the Scoped Service container.  Under normal circumstances, that's it.  You have the only reference to that object.  The service container created it and then dropped it's reference.  However. when you create a Transient service that implements `IDisposable/IAsyncDisposable`, the service container keeps a reference to it in it's objects to dispose list.

So no matter what strategy you apply, the scoped service container maintains a reference to the service and the GC doesn't remove it until the scoped service container itself is disposed and removed from memory.

There is a solution.  Create the instance outside the scoped service container using `ActivatorUtilities` and dispose it manually.

First a simple interface and implementation.

```cs
public interface ITransientService { }

public class TransientService : ITransientService, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Register it as a scoped service (you don't need to use it that way).

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITransientService, TransientService>();
```

Implemented in a component.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject IServiceProvider ServiceProvider
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    private ITransientService? _transientService;
    private IDisposable? _disposable;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Get the concrete service defined for the interface in the services container
        var service = this.ServiceProvider.GetService<ITransientService>();
        // and get the type
        var type = service?.GetType();

        if (type is not null)
        {
            // create a concreate instance from the service container
            _transientService = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(ServiceProvider, type) as ITransientService;
            // assign if disposable
            _disposable = _transientService as IDisposable;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

#### Additional Information

Creating a special Scoped service container for your context seems like a good solution.  You can dispose it when you've finished with it, and all the Transient services will be disposed properly.

There's a fundamental flaw to that solution.  Many Transient services have dependencies on Scoped services.  Consider how the Scoped service container obtains it's instance of Scoped services.  It creates them:  it is a Scoped container.  It doesn't get them from the parent container. So if you're service needs say the `AuthenticationService` or `NavigationManager`, it gets a newly created instance, not the one for the SPA session.

Comment: Thanks for answer! So if I am not wrong your answer is similar to [this topic](https://medium.com/@SleepyDaddySoft/scoped-dependency-injection-in-server-side-blazor-c759db967dc0) .Which says to inject IServiceScopeFactory to create custom scope inside my .razor and dispose them after using them.

Comment: Sort of, but `OwningComponentBase` is next to useless, which is why you rarely see it used.  See the *Additional Information* in my answer on why.